# How to access child records from an inner query in apex

Tags: soql, inner-join, outer-join

I have a piece of code in my Apex:

```
List<sObject> assessmentToQuestions = [
            SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM zced__Assessment_Questions__r) questions
            FROM zced__Assessment__c
            WHERE zced__Interaction__c = :interactionId
        ];

        Set<String> questionsIds = new Set<String>();
        for(sObject assessment: assessmentToQuestions) {
            for(sObject question: assessment.questions) {
                questionsIds.add(question);
            }
        }
```

The code above does not work because it does not allow me to use alias for the list of `Id` over here:

```
(SELECT Id FROM zced__Assessment_Questions__r) questions
```

I saw the application of an alias over [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_alias.htm) and tried to do the same, but got an error. So, my question here is how can I use an alias in the case?

Oh (this question in case if it is an `x-y problem`) how can I approach the problem of iterating the list in another way? I need to be able to iterate over all the `Id` extracted over here:

```
(SELECT Id FROM zced__Assessment_Questions__r)
```

Comment: You may find my answer on [converting sql to soql](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156278/converting-sql-to-soql/156300#156300) to be helpful (in addition to the answer you've already gotten here)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alias does not work with parent-to-child queries; however, you can access the query result set of zced__Assessment_Questions__r as follows:

```
for (zced__Assessment__c zced__Assessment : [
        SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM zced__Assessment_Questions__r)
        FROM zced__Assessment__c
        WHERE zced__Interaction__c = :interactionId
]) {
    zced__Assessment.zced__Assessment_Questions__r;
}
```

Comment: You're quite right but the phrase "aggregation query" might be confusing here (this isn't a SOQL aggregate query, where aliasing *is* supported; it's a non-aggregate parent-child query).

Comment: Rather than explaining where Aliasing is not supported, explain where it is supported.