# SOQL Query Inner Join

Tags: soql, query, workbench, inner-join

Could you please help me with the syntaxis of this SOQL Query? I would like to do an INNER JOIN between A and B on A.FamilyMember=B.ID

**SELECT** A.FamilyMember__c

**FROM** A

**WHERE** A.StartDate__c > TODAY  **AND** A.EndDate__c < TODAY

**AND** (**SELECT** ID **FROM** B **Where** Membre__c = True)

Comment: SOQL does not have a notion of an inner join as such. Instead, we use [Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm). I don't think I follow the final `AND` clause well enough to make a suggestion, though - can you add more description of your objective and your Salesforce data model?

Comment: You might find https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156278/converting-sql-to-soql/156300 to be helpful. In my answer on that question, I go into a fair bit of depth about "joins" in SOQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select Id, FamilyMember__c
from A
where StartDate__c > TODAY
    and EndDate__c < TODAY
    and FamilyMember__c in (
        select Id
        from B
        where Membre__c = true
        )
```

---

this SOQL is split into 2 parts:

- select Ids of `B` with condition (`Membre__c = True`),  this is inner select
- select `A` with condition (`FamilyMember__c` is in ids of records from previous step)

Comment: But by that way, Id field shows the Id values of the A Object. I want to display the Id field of the object B.

Comment: according to your data model in question, `Id` of `B` is stored in `FamilyMember__c` field on `A` object.