# How can i combine my variable to with soql command

Tags: apex, soql, inner-join

Hello friends firstly i get field data in contact object and after i start the loop till OwnerId and after i want to combine with my soql command i took error message

**Error Message: Unexpected token 'OwnerIds'.**

**This is my apex code **

```
 List<Contact> OwnerIds = new List<Contact>();
OwnerIds = [Select Contact.OwnerId From Contact Limit 1];

for (Integer i=0;i<OwnerIds.size();i++)
{
    List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id,OwnerId,(SELECT Id,OwnerId FROM Contacts) 
               FROM Account
                         Where OwnerId = OwnerIds];

    System.debug(acc);
}
```

**And I Try This**

```
List<Contact> OwnerIds = new List<Contact>();
OwnerIds = [Select Contact.OwnerId From Contact Limit 1];

for (Integer i=0;i<OwnerIds.size();i++)
{
    List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id,OwnerId,(SELECT Id,OwnerId FROM Contacts) 
               FROM Account
                         Where OwnerId =]OwnerIds;

    System.debug(acc);
}
```

**Then i take my error message: Unexpected token ']'.**

Comment: I've provided an answer here, but because I have context from your previous question, I'm not sure that this is really what you want to be doing. It's generally helpful if you try to explain _what  you're trying to accomplish_ with your code. It could be that the approach you've chosen isn't the easiest way to do things. If you give us an idea about what you're trying to accomplish, the community is usually pretty good about guiding you away from approaches that may end up causing issues.

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, go and take a look at https://trailhead.salesforce.com . Trailhead is a good way to become familiar with the basics of Salesforce (and the concepts used on the Salesforce platform). I don't think you'll become a Salesforce master just by completing modules over there, but becoming familiar with the platform helps you begin to construct more advanced things.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is called a *variable bind*.

The documentation on that [can be found here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm).

Taking a small excerpt from that page...

> SOQL and SOSL statements in Apex can reference Apex code variables and expressions if they’re preceded by a colon (:). This use of a local code variable within a SOQL or SOSL statement is called a bind. The Apex parser first evaluates the local variable in code context before executing the SOQL or SOSL statement.

So, your `WHERE` clause should end up looking like `WHERE OwnerId = :ownerIds]`

That said, your example here contains a query inside of a loop, which is a bad thing. Salesforce gives us a total of 100 queries that can be used in a single (synchronous) transaction, and queries inside of loops is a good way to burn through those.

Good practice here is to remove the query from the loop. There's no reason why you can't simply throw the results of your first query directly into the `WHERE` clause for your second query.

Comment: thank you finally i seeing join tables :D

Comment: @FurkanKuyular I don't advise trying to force SOQL into the mold of SQL. Again, I think of SOQL more like an ORM than anything else. If you think it might help you, I [wrote an answer on a question about converting SQL to SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156278/converting-sql-to-soql/156300#156300) where I went into a good amount of detail.

Answer (score 1):

You should remaster your code like this:

```
//with LIMIT 1

List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
contacts = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Contact LIMIT 1];

if (contacts.size() > 0) {
    String ownerId = contacts[0].OwnerId;
    List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = :ownerId];
}
```

Or like this:

```
//without specified LIMIT

List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
contacts = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Contact];

if (contacts.size() > 0) {
    Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Contact contact_i : contacts) {
        ownerIds.add(contact_i.OwnerId);
    }

    List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN :ownerIds];
}
```

**Explanation**:

1) First problem: you are looking at `List<Contact> OwnerIds` as on the List of Ids, however, it is a list of sObjects.

2) Second problem: you need to use `:` when referring the variables in SOQL.

3) Third problem: if you are referring collection, you need to use `IN` keyword, not just `=`.

Please, find some time to look through SF documentation on building SOQLs with examples, it will help you in future: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm

Comment: Yes thanks its worked got it :D