# Joining Contacts Table with Account

Tags: soql

I am trying to write a similar sql query in SOQL and this is what I have tried so far in SOQL but getting traceback. How can I write this query in Salesforce?

**SOQL** -- I need this soql query to be written in such a way that it gives the same output as below sql query

```
SELECT Account.country,count(Contact.id)
FROM Account
where Contact.url_field != null -- and other criteria
group by Account.country
```

**SQL**

```
select acnt.country
,COUNT(DISTINCT cntct.id)  
FROM contact as cntct
inner join account as acnt
ON acnt.id = cntct.accountid
where cntct.url_field is not null
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR at Row:1:Column:34
Didn't understand relationship 'contact' in field path. If you are attempting to use 
a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. 
Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/384334/edit) your question to add the *exact* error text.

Comment: @Moonpie Just added. Thanks.

Comment: Does [this other question that I answered](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156278/converting-sql-to-soql/156300#156300) re: SQL vs SOQL point you in the right direction?

Comment: @DerekF Tried but not able to implement in Salesforce language. Can you please help translate the sql query into soql query if possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A core misconception you may have is that your field path in any given [field expression](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm) can originate from any joined table. Not so in SOQL. Each field expression must reference a field path originating from your query root object (the top level `FROM` clause). That means you can only look "up" to parent objects, never "down" to child objects.* As such, you have your relationship backwards. One `Account` has many child `Contact` records. So `Contact` has a field pointing to `AccountId`.

As far as the field expression syntax goes, another point of confusion is you are putting the root object in some of your fields, not others. You should not use it at all. So instead the query you are trying would be more clearly written as:

```
SELECT Country, count(Contact.id)
FROM Account
WHERE Contact.Url_Field__c != null
GROUP BY Country
```

However, that doesn't work because there is no `ContactId` field to join on. Note that the **[`Account`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm)** object has no `ContactId` field, but the **[`Contact`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm)** object does have `AccountId`. Your corrected query should instead use `Contact` as the root object.

```
SELECT Account.Country, count(Id)
FROM Contact
WHERE Url_Field__c != null
GROUP BY Account.Country
```

---

- Except for sub-selects, which have their own syntax and are not supported in aggregate queries.

Comment: I tried your query but I am getting this error. "UNKNOWN ERROR: Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string"

Comment: That error cannot possibly be generated by the SOQL itself. How are you running this query?

Comment: I am getting this error in workbench developerforce com and when I am running this query in Salesforce console, the error is no response from the server. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Aggregate Functions for SOQL https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm
You can query on the child object (Contact) and group by the parent (Account)

As an example, the query below gives a count of contacts per country - is this in the right direction? Can you provide the current output of your SQL statement as a guide?

```
AggregateResult[] aggRes = [
SELECT Account.BillingCountry, Count(Id) countOfContacts FROM Contact GROUP BY Account.BillingCountry];
```

Gives result:

```
(AggregateResult:{BillingCountry=Australia, countOfContacts=1}, 
 AggregateResult:{BillingCountry=France, countOfContacts=3}, 
 AggregateResult:{BillingCountry=Italy, countOfContacts=2}, 
 AggregateResult:{BillingCountry=United States, countOfContacts=81}, 
 AggregateResult:{BillingCountry=null, countOfContacts=8})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your exact error message, you need to use `where Contact.url_field != null`.

I'm assuming `url_field` is shorthand for whatever field you're trying to query

Comment: I used this and the error got changed