# How to query in master-details objects?

Tags: soql

how to get the field name in master details objects?
I have 3 Custom Object.

**A Object(Master):**

```
Fields: Id, Name
```

**B Object(Master):**

```
Fields: Id, Name
```

**C Object(Detail):**

```
Fields: Master-detail(Object A), Master-detail(Object B), Name
```

How can i do query like this:

`Select A.Name, B.Name, C.Name From A, B, C Where A.Name = 'name condition'`

Comment: While not a direct answer to your question, I think my answer on [this other question on converting SQL to SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156278/converting-sql-to-soql/156300#156300) may help.

Comment: Thank for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to query on detail object and reference your master fields in that query.
Example -
Master object-

> Master__c
> Fields of Master__c - Id, Name

Detail object-

> Detail__c
> Fields of Detail__c - Id, Name, Master__c

Then your query will be like -

```
  SELECT Id, Name, Master__r.Name FROM Detail__c WHERE Master__r.Name = 'name condition'
```

Comment: Many thanks, have a nice  day bro